# IE8 issues on Windows 7 RC

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, sophos

I'm running Windows 7 RC and noticed today that when trying to launch IE nothing happend. The only way to launch IE was to right-click and Run As Administrator.

Comment: I asked Jacob via email to paste in the answer that was in the original question. Please don't vote on this until that happens.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out this is because of Sophos Antivirus. This is because of the webscanning component.

To fix do the following:

1. Create a key named Webscanning under the Sophos key:

   32-bit:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Sophos\Webscanning`

   64-bit:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node\Sophos\Webscanning`
2. Create a DWORD registry key named SuppressBHOLoader with a value of 1 at 
   the above location"